# How to catch (and display on the client) server-side OData business validation errors in JayData using AngularJs

Tags: jaydata

If I am using code such as this (from: http://jaydata.org/blog/jaydata-and-angularjs-continued):

$scope.saveChanges = function () {

```
$scope.northwind.saveChanges()
.then(function () {
  $scope.selectedProduct = null;
},function() {
  $scope.northwind.stateManager.reset();
});
```

};

How do I catch any server-side business validation errors that the server may return?

Comment: the second callback function is called in case of an error and that function should receive the info back... we'll have automatic client side validation based on the $metadata soon

Comment: Thank you, that was the answer I was looking for :) I did try to look through the API documentation but I guess this API is only a few days old :)

Comment: actually, it's angularjs $q promise implementation (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q),
then(successCallback, errorCallback)
usually we use jquery promise where the syntax is different, like
saveChange()
.then(function() {})
.fail(function() {})

Comment: Again, thank You! I now see I can parse the validation messages from LightSwitch contained in "<ValidationResults><ValidationResult><Message>". I need to finish my article this weekend so I will do it myself. When you put it into JayData that will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
$scope.saveChanges = function () {
    $scope.ApplicationData.saveChanges()
    .then(function () {
        $scope.selectedToDo = null;
    }, function (error) {
        var xml = error.message,
        xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
        $xml = $(xmlDoc),
        $ValidationResults = $xml.find("ValidationResults");

        angular.forEach($ValidationResults, function (ValidationResult) {
            angular.forEach(ValidationResult.childNodes, function (childNode) {
                alert(childNode.childNodes[0].textContent);
            });
        });

        $scope.ApplicationData.stateManager.reset();
    });
};
```

Comment: What about json response from OData?

Comment: Did you try the code? Did it not work? What error did you get?

Comment: I didn't because it says $.parseXml() which means the response is XML. Mine is json.

Comment: I have no examples, sorry.